# How can i move through items in a listBox using SelectedIndexChanged event and select only part of the item?

Tags: c#

This is the code how do i move through the items and show them in a label:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

But if i have 3 items for example:

```
Url: http://www.cnet.com --- Localy KeyWord: cnet
Url: http://www.google.com --- Localy KeyWord: google
Url: http://www.microsoft.com --- Localy KeyWord: microsoft
```

Then i want to show in the label4 only the url's of each item if im on the first item in label4 i will see only http://www.cnet.com if im on the second item so label4 will show only http://www.google.com and so on...to display in label4 only the websites addresses parts.

Comment: Is the format of your urls constant? What suffixes are allowed? This can easily be solved by regex.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: Jordan the urls are constant in the listBox the user can add new url's to the listBox in the same format item as above but the url's in the listBox cant be change. any suffixes i mean the url's in the listbox could be contain http://20%www.google.com043554TRtytr i want from the listBox only the part between the Url: and the --- Localy KeyWord: google so in this exmaple in label4 it will be http://www.google.com but it can be any type of url.

Comment: Cyborgx37 i tried after the user made a selection inside the listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event to use label4.Text.IndexOf and label4.Text.Substring but without any success so far. i did: label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int i = listBox1.Text.IndexOf("Url:");
            string t = label4.Text.Substring(i); but its not working the results are not what i wanted.

Comment: Slow down and try to write a complete sentence, with punctuation. Also, you should be updating your question, not flooding the comments with additional information. See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the long way i guess but its working:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                string startTag = "Url: ";
                string endTag = " ---";
                int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
                int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
                int index = 0;
                index = label4.Text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = label4.Text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                string g = label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);
                label4.Text = g;
            }
        }
```

Thanks.